# Div Not Stretching Height to Bottom of Window Even with HTML and Body Heights at 100%

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a div that stretches to the bottom of the window, so that any overflow of the div content will trigger a scroll. I looked online to see how to make a div stretch to the bottom of the window, and everything said to make `html` and `body` both have `height: 100%;`. I have done that, and it still doesn't work. Relevant code is below:

**html:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="tasks">
  <div class="tasklist row-fluid span8 offset2">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      {{#each model}}
        {{partial 'tasks/taskListElement'}}
      {{/each}}
    </table>
  </div>
</script>
```

**css:**

```
html, body {height: 100%;}

.tasklist {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've enclosed your `div.tasklist` inside a `script` tag that might be the problem, it gets the 100% height of its parent which is the `script#tasks`. `<script>` has its own style, try also applying 100% height on `script#tasks`

Comment: you got me on the right track, but I found it was a different answer. I am using Ember.js, and when it renders each view, it encapsulates it in a div with a class of `ember-view`. I made that also a height of 100%, and that made it work. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a reset css file attached? If not, some browsers add a margin or padding as default so you end up with a gap. Here's a link to it.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/